# Border-radius and overflow:hidden (ionic app)

Tags: ios, css, ionic-framework, overflow

Have some problems with border-radius and overflow:hidden in Ionic app.
I got parent .dtc-zero-eye and .dtc-zero-iris child.

```
.dtc-zero-eye {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 8.5vh;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
  border: 8px solid #DCDDE1;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 20vh;
  height: 20vh;
  border-radius: 5% 125% 5% 125%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  overflow: hidden;

  .dtc-zero-iris {
    width: 12vh;
    height: 12vh;
    background-color: #2D9AFF;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
```

Everything works great when try in chrome (debug mode).

[image: Chrome]

But when try in test sketch on ios device - have these =>

[image: ios]

So when I turn the border-radius off - overflow works right way.
Of course tried some fixes like "mask-image" but as expected it does not work.

I really waiting for your answers guys , and sorry for my bad english.

Updated , here are the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3or6r66m/)

Comment: What does it look like with the radius off? Would be really useful to have a jsFiddle or similar for this.

Comment: Thanks for your attention , here are the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/3or6r66m/) you can just erase border radius and see what it's like.

Comment: Maybe iOS uses the outside of the border to clip the contents? Try turning off the border.

Comment: Greeat Thanks!!! i tried and found out that you right - iOS really uses the outside of the border for clipping. I think you have to post it like and answer , to make the question solved?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe iOS uses the outside of the border to clip the contents? Try turning off the border and seeing what happens.

Comment: "Greeat Thanks!!! i tried and found out that you right - iOS really uses the outside of the border for clipping."